# How do I pass variables into a function, with any signature, using templates?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, c++14

My problem is the following. I want to call any free function within a wrapper, and I want to pass it parameters automatically within the wrapper.

The idea is to pass the arguments via function calls like `GetArgument<float>()`. Ultimately I want to get the values from a virtual machine, and pass them to the function I am binding. I need to place the correct `GetArgument<T>` with the correct type at the correct position within the function call.

Here's a minimal working example of my attempt. Main:

```
#include "FunctionWrapper.h"
#include <iostream>

void say( int val ) {
    std::cout << "called with " << val << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    InvokeWithArguments( say );

    return 0;
}
```

And here's where the magic happens. I get a compiler error towards the end of the source:

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

/*
 * FUNCTION TRAITS
 */
template< typename F >
struct FunctionTraits;

template< typename R, typename... Args >
struct FunctionTraits< R( Args... ) > {
    using ReturnType = R;

    constexpr static const uint32_t arity = sizeof...( Args );

    template< std::size_t N >
    struct Argument {
        static_assert( N < arity, "FunctionTraits error: invalid argument count parameter" );
        using type = typename std::tuple_element< N, std::tuple< Args... > >::type;
    };
};

/*
 * ARGUMENT GETTER (for demonstration)
 **/
template< typename T >
T GetArgument() {}

template<>
float GetArgument() {
    return 3.3f;
}

template<>
int GetArgument() {
    return 5;
}

/*
 * AUTOMATIC INVOCATION
 **/
template< typename Function, std::size_t... index >
decltype( auto ) InvokeHelper( Function&& f, std::index_sequence<index...> ) {
    using Traits = FunctionTraits< decltype(f) >;
    // COMPILER FAILS HERE, EXPECTS ) BEFORE :: TOKEN
    return f( GetArgument< Traits::Argument<index>::type >()... );
}

template< typename Function >
decltype( auto ) InvokeWithArguments( Function&& f ) {
    constexpr auto Arity = FunctionTraits< decltype(f) >::arity;
    return InvokeHelper( std::forward<Function>( f ), std::make_index_sequence<Arity>{} );
}
```

I don't understand why `return f( GetArgument< Traits::Argument<index>::type >()... );` fails. As far as I can tell, `Traits::Argument<index>::type` is a type, so I don't know why the compiler would expect to close the function call in the midst of it.

Finally, a small sanity check, since I'm such a template programming noob. I want there to be a comma-separated list of calls to `GetArgument<T>` in between the parenthesis of the function call. Is that even what my code is doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
return f( GetArgument< typename Traits::template Argument<index>::type >()... );
//                     ^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^
```

After this the compiler will complain that your `FunctionTraits<void(&)(int)>` cannot be instanciated, which can be fixed by removing the reference in the function type via `std::remove_reference`.

This is caused by the fact that `void(int)` is different from `void(&)(int)` is different from `void(*)(int)`. The first is a function type, the second is a function reference type and the latter is a function pointer type.

All of this will yield:

```
template< typename Function, std::size_t... index >
decltype( auto ) InvokeHelper( Function&& f, std::index_sequence<index...> ) {
    using Traits = FunctionTraits< typename std::remove_reference<decltype(f)>::type >;
    //                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^
    return f( GetArgument< typename Traits::template Argument<index>::type >()... );
    //                     ^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^
}

template< typename Function >
decltype( auto ) InvokeWithArguments( Function&& f ) {
    constexpr auto Arity = FunctionTraits< typename std::remove_reference<decltype(f)>::type >::arity;
    //                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^           ^^^^^^^
    return InvokeHelper( std::forward<Function>( f ), std::make_index_sequence<Arity>{} );
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/860f7f2443a0f301)